# CSS toggle button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova

Is it possible to have a CSS toggle button in PhoneGAP ?
 I want a button that changes color if clicked and when clicked again it must go back to default color . Any idea how to do it in ?

I've edited my post my it can be easy fro you guys to help me out ,because now i'm really confused on how to do this,the simple stuff but trick.

```
  `This the function 

  function toggle(ths) {

   //CSS color
   $(ths).toggleClass("btnColor");
   $("#tb").toggleClass("btnColorR")

   //Get value clicked
   var clicked = $(ths).val();

   //diplay on web-page
   $("#lblType").html(clicked);
   $("#setCount").html(" minutes : " + minutes + " seconds : " + seconds);

   //duration time count
   seconds = seconds + 1;
   if (seconds % 60 == 0) {
      minutes += 1;
   seconds = 0;
 }
        timer = setTimeout("toggle()", 1000);   
  }


 The CSS

.btnColor
 {
 background-color:blue;  
 color:white;  
 }
.btnColorR {
 background-color:green;
}


  This is how my buttons are created.

 function createButtons(tbID, tbClass, tbType, tbValue, onClick) {
     return '\n<input '
        + (tbID ? ' id=\'' + tbID + '\'' : '')
        + (tbClass ? ' class=\'' + tbClass + '\'' : '')
        + (tbType ? ' type=\'' + tbType + '\'' : '')
        + (tbValue ? ' value=\'' + tbValue + '\'' : '')
        + (onClick ? ' onclick=\'toggle(this);' + onClick + '\'' : '')
        + '>';
 }

 function DisplayButtons(cableData) {
  var newContent = '';
   $.each(cableData,

    function (i, item) {
       newContent += createButtons("tb" + item.CommonCable, null, "submit",       item.CommonCable, toggle);
   });
   $("#planned").html(newContent);
 }`
```

Answer (score 5):

consider that your button is `#butt`:

```
$("#butt").click(function(){
     $(this).toggle('red');
})
```

and CSS:

```
.red{
 color:red;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot man but still it does not work ,my css was working before i moved to Phonegap i dont know ehy this is happening ,was even thinking maybe i'm crazy now. thanks again

Comment: see if `$("#butt").click(function(){alert(1)});` is working at all.

Comment: it does not work ,can i edit my post and include code how my button is created with the css

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is a library which helps your mobile web app have all the features of a native appliccation. So for designing your application you can use anything like html or any js framework like Sencha, Jquery, YUI, JQM..etc. and make application package using phonegap.

You will be able to access all the native features like camera, contacts, acclerometers..etc using the Phonegap classes.
So your CSS toggle button will work in any case. There is nothing Phonegap will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggle(ths)
{
    if ($(ths).attr('class') == "btnColor") {
        $(ths).removeClass("btnColor");
        $(ths).addClass("btnColorR");
    } else {
        $(ths).removeClass("btnColorR");
        $(ths).addClass("btnColor");
    }
}

function createButtons(tbID, tbClass, tbType, tbValue, onClick)
{
    return '\n<input '
    + (tbID ? ' id=\'' + tbID + '\'' : '')
    + (tbClass ? ' class=\'' + tbClass + '\'' : '')
    + (tbType ? ' type=\'' + tbType + '\'' : '')
    + (tbValue ? ' value=\'' + tbValue + '\'' : '')
    + (onClick ? ' onclick=\''+onClick(this)+';\'' : '')
    + '>';
}
```

Comment: it works fine when im not using PhoneGap but once i try on PhoneGap it does not work. i think i need some time with PHoneGap Books

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need JS for that, because it can be done with CSS only depending on your browser matrix. Basically you use a checkbox, hide it and style the belonging label how you need it. Then you can switch the styling via the `:checked` and `:not(:checked)` selectors on clivk (be sure to check browser support). Demo: http://custom-inputs.felixhagspiel.de/

I wrote a tutorial about how to customize checkboxes and radios with CSS only, as well as create on/off toggle switches. Maybe this helps :) You can change the styling as you want. Read the tutorial here: http://blog.felixhagspiel.de/index.php/posts/custom-inputs